# Multi-Variable normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am student of statistics and in probability course we have to solve a question about multi variable normally distribution,I know in single variable normally distribution we can standardize our random variable and use the table to find probability value,but in Multi-Variable normal distribution I don't know how to use the table an for this special question can you help me or give me a general solution for this types problem.
Problem:
Suppose the profit of a store for 2 consecutive weeks(X,Y) in millions of dollars, both from distribution N(40,36)  Follow and distribute
Their sum from N(40,40,36,36,0.6)
Corr(X,Y)=0.6
What is the probability X+Y≥90

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I have just edit my question.It is good enough?

Comment: Why should it be? It is still phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context.

Comment: I am new and I don't what kind of information should I add to my question can you help me?

Comment: What you need to do is find the distribution of $X+Y$, which (if these are jointly bivariate normal) you can do to produce a univariate normal distribution.  What have you tried?

Comment: I know Z1=X-mux/sigma x,Z2=Y-muY/Sigma Y can standardize our random variable but I want to find Z'1,Z'2 as two standard normal distribution and independence,How can I found this variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the problem is a little confusing, because the *sum* of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ is just another *real random variable*, so it doesn't make sense to say that it has a *bivariate* normal distribution, and $\ N(40,40,36,36,0.6)\ $ is not a common way of representing a bivariate normal distribution in any case.  The usual way of representing a bivariate normal distribution is $\ N(\mu, \Sigma)\ ,$ where $\ \mu\ $ is the $2\times1\ $ vector of means $\big($here, presumably $\ \mu=(40,40)\ \big)$ of the two random variables, and $\ \Sigma\ $ is their [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix). Since you're told the correlation coefficient
\begin{align}
\text{Corr}(X,Y)&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{\text{Cov(X,Y)}}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\\
&=\frac{\text{Cov(X,Y)}}{36}
\end{align}
in your case is $0.6$, you must have $\ \text{Cov}(X,Y)=$$\ 0.6\times36=$$\,21.6\ $, and therefore
$$
\Sigma=\pmatrix{36&21.6\\21.6&36}\ .
$$

To get the distribution of $\ X+Y\ $ you can use the fact that the sum of two variables that follow a bivariate normal distribution must be normally distributed, so all you have to do is calculate its mean and variance, which you can easily do from the mean and covariance of the bivariate normal:
\begin{align}
E(X+Y)&=E(X)+E(Y)\\
&=80\\
\text{Var}(X+Y)&=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\,\text{Cov}(X,Y)\\
&=115.2\ .
\end{align}
Thus, $\ X+Y\sim N(80,115.2)\ ,$ from which you should easily be able to compute the probability that $\ X+Y\ge90\ $.

Comment: Thank a lot, It solve my problem.